# Is there a way to find out what files are taking up the most space on my HTC One?

Tags: android

I have a HTC One, running the most recent version of Android - 6.0.

I'm running low on internal storage. All of my music is stored on the SD card and I've deleted almost all images and videos from my phone, so I'm not sure what's taking up almost 10gigs of space.

I have a few games, Clash of Clans and Dungeon Boss are probably the largest.

Is there an app which can break down where and what is taking up so much of my phone's memory?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android's own Storage options `(Settings - Storage)` and file managers such as [Solid Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.solidexplorer2&hl=en) can display storage usage statistics. You can use these to see what's taking up space.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get a hint in andriod's storage setting:
http://www.androidcentral.com/sites/androidcentral.com/files/postimages/1278254/screenshot_2013-03-23-13-18-04.png